# Cocoapod can't identify my target after it was renamed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I had been using cocoapods to pod stuff but after I've renamed my whole xcode project, the cocoapod doesn't reconise my renamed target when I am trying to pod lottie, and I don't know how to replace the target with the new one

This error showed in terminal

```
[!] Unable to find a target named `Infinity Math`, did find `Infinity Math.temp_caseinsensitive_rename`, `Infinity Math.temp_caseinsensitive_renameTests`, and `Infinity Math.temp_caseinsensitive_renameUITests`.
```

My Pod file

```
platform :ios, '12.0'

target 'Infinity Math' do

    use_frameworks!

pod 'UITextField+Shake', '~> 1.2'
pod 'SPAlert'
pod 'CBFlashyTabBarController'
pod 'Spring', :git => 'https://github.com/MengTo/Spring.git'
pod 'lottie-ios'

target 'InfinityMathTests' do

    inherit! :search_paths

end

target 'InfinityMathUITests' do

    inherit! :search_paths

end

end
```

What should I do next in order to pod new pods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it by renaming the target to the ones in the error

`InfinityMath.temp_caseinsensitive_rename`,
`InfinityMath.temp_caseinsensitive_renameTests`, `InfinityMath.temp_caseinsensitive_renameUITests`

It's weird

Answer (score 0):

Give the targets in the Podfile the same names that show up in Xcode:

```
target 'Infinity Math' do

target 'Infinity MathTests' do

target 'Infinity MathUITests' do
```

Comment: I've changed all the names in xcode to InfinityMath, but the same error occured ```[!] Unable to find a target named `InfinityMath`, did find `InfinityMath.temp_caseinsensitive_rename`, `InfinityMath.temp_caseinsensitive_renameTests`, and `InfinityMath.temp_caseinsensitive_renameUITests`.``` I've changed the target name to the ones in xcode